# Why I can't edit XMLs in my Custom Layout Update via CMS?

Tags: magento2, admin, xml, cms

I had layout updates via XML configurations per CMS page via admin panel as you can see below.

[image: Magento 2 layout update XML]

After updating my Magento 2.3 I got another option instead.

How could I add my layout changes with an updated Magento?

Answer (score 1):

It's a new security measure introduced since Magento 2.3.4. [The goal is to remove the opportunity for Remote Code Execution (RCE)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html#highlights).

In the new method, you need to create the XML changes in a file, and Magento shows the options to customize the CMS page. You can create your XML files inside the folder below, and the name of the file must follow the syntax mentioned in the [Magento 2 DevDocs Compose the layout update in the XML section](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/layout-update-place-block.html#step-2-compose-the-layout-update-in-xml).

```
<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layout
```

[image: Magento 2 Custom Layout Update]